# File configuration Hibernate 4 and spring 3

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-3, hibernate-4.x

I started with the new technology with spring 3 hibernate 4, and I tried to do the following examples from a tutorial. Each time I get the same errors. I work with Spring 3.1.1 Hibernate 4.1.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:Bibliotheque" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />

    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.ardia.Adherent</value>
                <value>com.ardia.Emprunt</value>
                <value>com.ardia.Fournisseur</value>
                <value>com.ardia.Livre</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

<!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->

 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

This is the message and I do not understand it:

Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor'. See Error Log for more details

Error occured processing '/Hibernate_spring/src/application_configuration.xml'

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:126)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:375)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:421)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the spring-tx.jar, spring-orm.jar and hibernate-entitymanager.jar files for the appropriate versions on your classpath.

Also in your configuration notice that the `transactionManager` is incorrectly referenced.

```
<!-- An id of txManager is assigned here -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

<!-- While transactionManager is referenced here -->    
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

This line of configuration should change the `transaction-manager` to point to the `txManager` bean:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Comment: I have this jar on my library org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar .and i m not using Maven

Comment: <!-- An id of txManager is assigned here -->
    <bean id="txmanager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

<!-- While transactionManager is referenced here -->    
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txmanager"/>

Comment: do you have spring-orm.jar and hibernate-entitymanager.jar on your classpath?

Comment: MY NEW MESSAGE error Error occured processing XML 'org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor'. See Error Log for more details

Comment: Now you need spring-aop.jar

Comment: @FERESSS Glad everything is working.  Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The  `spring-tx.jar` file should be there in your classpath meaning it should present in `(i.e. WEB-INF/lib)` folder of your application

Check whether you have exactly only one of that `spring-tx.jar` having multiple jars of the same type can also result in `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: it is the same :( i have all the jar spring 3.1 and i creat my own library attached to the project .and I check there is one jar transaction named  org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this aopalliance jar binds your transaction manager to your spring application